# Can I make Sublime Text replace function behave more like the one of Notepad++?

Tags: sublimetext2

Let's say I want to perform 2 replacements in a file: replace "member" with "player" and "Member" with "Player".

In Notepad++ the Replace function lives in a window. During the first replacement this window doesn't move (while stuff is being replaced behind it), so to proceed with the second replacement I simply change the letters in the very same window and it "replace" again. Super easy.

In Sublime Text two things make this harder:

1) After the first replacement, the fields of the Replace function disappear. So you have to open the Replace function again

2) Once you open it again, the "Find What" field and the "Replace With" fields both have the same value! So you must type the entire word again in "Find What" field. Laborious.

But I don't know Sublime Text well and perhaps I'm doing it wrong. Any suggestion to make the process smoother like in Np++?

Comment: Just tried this and if I understood correctly the replace window doesn't close in sublime text 3? But if this doesn't work then it's likely unfixable as sublime is closed source.

Comment: It doesn't close on Notepad++, which is good because then you can go on with other replacements. In does close on Sublime, which is very unfortunate because you have to re-open it and re-retype one of the fields entirely

Comment: Did you try sublime text 3?

Comment: That's the one I'm using, Sublime 3.

Comment: In your case I recommend using `MultiEditUtils` plugin's `Preserve Case` command. It can replace the all selected words without breaking the cases (single replace). Example usage: select all `member`, `Member`, `MEMBER` etc. words run `Preserve Case` command, write `player` press `Enter` and all selected words will change to `player` without breaking the cases.